# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left| C_n \right|}<+\infty $

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-analysis

Assume there's a real function $f\in C^{1}[0,\pi]$. Let
$$
C_n=\int_0^{\pi}{f\left( x \right) \cos \left( nx \right) \text{d}x},\quad n=1,2,3,\cdots
$$
Prove that, $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left| C_n \right|}<+\infty $$

I don't have any ideas after a long time of thinking. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is equivalent to study $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n}|\int_{0}^{\pi}f'(x)\sin(nx)|$

Comment: There's a counterexample below. Probably you just omitted a hypothesis, for example $f(\pi)=f(0)$.

Comment: What’s the counter example?

Comment: An $L^2$ function has Fourier Coefficients in $l^2.$ But this does not help directly here because it is requiring $l^1.$ Maybe this stronger statement comes from the stricter requirement that is continuously-differentiable rather than just square-integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not grossly mistaken, then I think it works as follows:

Expand $f$ over to the whole $I = [-\pi,\pi]$ by reflecting along the $y$ -  axis. This gives an even function $g\in C^1[-\pi,\pi].$ Then, $g'$ is an $L^2$ function with Fourier coefficients $c_n\sim O(n^{-1}).$ This means $g$ has Fourier coefficients that are of the order $O(n^{-2})$ and so it is absolutely summable.